# Throwing Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have a problem when I ask the user for the amount to be withdrawn from their balance.
I have a method called withdraw, and i pass their balance. Then I want to check if the amount that they want to withdraw is less than their balance. If yes, I would like to make the user to retry.

So far, it checks for the input but i keep getting an output for each try.

```
public void withdraw (double balance)
{
    System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
    double amount = keyboard.nextDouble();  

    try
    {
        if(amount > balance)
        {
            throw new IncorrectWithdrawException();
        }
    }
    catch(IncorrectWithdrawException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        withdraw(balance);// keeps calling the method for a loop if they keep entering incorrect amount
    }
    balance = balance-amount;
    System.out.println("You have withdrawn "+amount+ " and your new balance is " +balance);
}
```

Output:

What is your balance? 100
How much would you like to withdraw?200
------ERROR------ That is not a valid amount to withdraw. 
How much would you like to withdraw? 500
------ERROR------ That is not a valid amount to withdraw. 
How much would you like to withdraw? 50

You have withdrawn 50.0 and your new balance is 50.0
You have withdrawn 500.0 and your new balance is -400.0
You have withdrawn 200.0 and your new balance is -100.0

I do not want the last two outputs...

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Calling the same method (recursively) from inside the exception handler? Now there's a pattern I haven't seen before...

Comment: Is it possible that you are starting with a zero balance?

Comment: i start with a balance of 100. then i say withdraw 200 so it prints the exception. Then it asks for a new amount to withdraw, but instead of comparing that, it starts from the begining

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity for learning to use a debugger to step through your code so you can understand what it's actually doing.

Comment: i am using a debugger but i cant fix it. That's why sometimes you are asking for someones help "assuming they know better than you"

Comment: You should not be using recursion here.  Throw the exception back to the caller of `withdraw` and have the caller do the retry.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you, but now i get 3 outputs when i finally use a smaller amount. See my edited version.

Comment: Remove the try/catch inside your `withdraw` routine and have one only in the caller.

Comment: @HotLicks what do u mean by caller? im a newbie :P I appreciate your help

Comment: The "caller" is the routine that calls `withdraw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when amount > balance, you've passed user's next input as new balance, which is very problematic... user can cheat the balance

Answer (score 2):

Don't use exceptions inside methods as a sneaky ninja way to effect if/then conditional code: that's not what they're for. Exceptions are a last defense against abnormal conditions that cannot be otherwise checked for. Your code has a perfectly normal description, and perfectly normal behaviour. Stick with normal `if`/`then`:

```
public void withdraw (double balance)
{
  double amount;
  do
  {
    System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
    amount = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if (amount > balance)
    {
      System.out.println("I'm sorry, you cannot overdraw, please pick a lower withdrawal amount.");
    }
  }
  while(amount > balance);

  // Although you probably want to say something like
  // "or type 0 not to withdraw anything", to be nice.

  balance = balance-amount;
  System.out.println("You have withdrawn "+amount+ " and your new balance is " +balance);
}
```

Comment: that's wonderful: don't. This is not what exceptions are for, and I'm not going to teach you how to write bad code. I *am* going to tell you not to teach yourself bad code: learn about how things are done in java. This is one such occasion.

Comment: :) thank you, the problem is that it is required for the program to throw an exception if you try to withdraw more money than your balance.

Comment: We normally don't use exceptions on a user level, they are more used to see what went wrong during the actual compile time. So unless this is for homework there really is no reason for you to do it.

Comment: so you don't "want" to use an exception, you "have to" use an exception because it's a homework assignment?

Comment: exactly! its one of the requirements.

Comment: @Tdorno - There is absolutely nothing wrong with using an exception in this case.

Comment: then I strongly recommend you get off stackoverflow and read your course material again. You won't use exceptions in real code for doing what you state, and you're asking about an artifial problem. Helping you solve your homework will not help others learn Java, which is what SO is for. Answers to your questions should help you and others, not just your homework.

Comment: I was asking for your help in order to understand this problem. If you don't think it is useful to help others, then i really hope that you will be successful in your life . You have been in my position and you know how it is. Thank you

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257570/withdraw-exception-java/20257756#20257756

Answer (score 0):

One important note:

You should check your balance to make sure it's larger or equal to 0.

(Assume you won't let negative balance happens.)